# How to compare two queries results in the same loop

Tags: javascript

I have 2 `sql queries` (each one for one semester). These 2 queriesdoes not have the same number of lines. Each one contain 3 parameters:  `Article  id_Customer Turnover`.

This following a request which compute the first semester:

```
select "LRU", "Client", round(sum("Montant_fac_eur"))
from "foundry_sync"."data"
where "Nature"='Repair'     

and extract(month from "Facturation") between 0+{{w_widget6.selectedValue}} and 5+{{w_widget6.selectedValue}}
group by "LRU", "Client"
```

The semester of the queries represents like this:

```
{
  "LRU": [
    "ATSU",
    "ATSU",
    "ATSU",
    "ATSU
      . 
      .
      .
   ],
"Client": [
    394,
    594,
    4001,
    5725,
    7057,
    7090
    .
    .
    .
],
 "round": [
    20866,
    16814,
    27421,
    0,
    6593,
    66965,
    8401
     . 
     .
     .
]
```

This following a sample of the result:

```
   result 1                      result2

"[Article1,394,3914]"      "[Article1,394,3914]"
"[Article1,594,16814]"     "[Article2,594,10088]"
"[Article1,4001,26798]"    "[Article1,4001,11107]"
"[Article3,5725,0]"        "[Article3,5725,0]"
"[Article5,7057,5700]"     "[Article5,7057,3916]"
"[Article8,7090,56467]"    "[Article4,7090,17558]"
"[Article2,7236,8401]"     "[Article8,7236,8401]"
"[Article11,7242,12766]"   "[Article14,7242,4255]"
"[Article2,7262,892]"      "[Article2,7262,892]"
"[Article3,7302,17234]"    "[Article3,7302,8928]"
```

As you see, a customer can have a turnover of an article in the both semesters, or one turnover of article in just one semester(in the first one or in the second one).
I want compare the turnover of each `Article` per `customer` in each semester first of all.

```
    var query1 = {{repair_semestre1}};
    var query2 = {{repair_semestre2}};
    var result1 = [];
    var result2 = [];


    for (var i = 0; i < query1.LRU.length; i++) {
      result1.push(formatName(query1.LRU[i], query1.Client[i], query1.round[i]));  
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < query2.LRU.length; i++) {
      result2.push(formatName(query2.LRU[i], query2.Client[i], query2.round[i]));  
    }

    return {
      result1: result1, 
      result2: result2
    };

   /*   for (var i = 0; i < query1.LRU.length, i < query2.LRU.length; i++) {
        if((query1.LRU[i] == query2.LRU[i]) && (query1.Client[i] == query2.Client[i])) {
                    if(query1.round[i] > query2.round[i]) {
                            return "ok";
                    }
                    else { return "non";
                    }
        }

    }  */

    function formatName(lru, turnover, round) {
      return "[" + lru + "," + turnover + "," + round + "]";
    }
```

I did a loop for these 2 queries outside the function to compare her results:

```
var query1 = {{repair_semestre1}};
var query2 = {{repair_semestre2}};
for (var i = 0; i < query1.LRU.length, i < query2.LRU.length; i++) {
    if((query1.LRU[i] == query2.LRU[i]) && (query1.Client[i] == query2.Client[i])) {
                if(query1.round[i] > query2.round[i]) {
                        return "ok";
                }
                else { return "not ok";
                }
    }   
}
```

it return just `not ok`, and do not complete the rest of the lines. Can one please, explain me why ?
And how can I add this loop in my function to run ?

Thank you.

Comment: Once `return` is encountered, your loop exits execution. Maybe you should create an array of results? If you post a working example, with proper data, I could try to help.

Comment: @MaazSyedAdeeb I edited my question, I added my function where I did the array of the tow queries. For the posting of the proper data, this one above are the proper data just I change the names of article by 1, 2 ,8,...I hope that I understand you. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @MaazSyedAdeeb please how can I resove this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to first convert your data structure to something that groups related things together in one object, instead of having links with index numbers.

For instance, for client 594, who is involved with two articles, the semester turn-overs could be represented like this:

```
{
  "594": {
    "Article1": [
      16814,
      0
    ],
    "Article2": [
      0,
      10088
    ]
  }
}
```

... where the inner array always has two entries: for each of the two semesters. That structure will allow for easy reporting.

Here is the code for the transformation with example output following it:

```js
// Sample data
const query1 = {
    LRU: ["Article1", "Article1", "Article1", "Article3", "Article5", 
          "Article8", "Article2", "Article11", "Article2", "Article3"], 
    Client: [394, 594, 4001, 5725, 7057, 7090, 7236, 7242, 7262, 7302],
    round: [3914, 16814, 26798, 0, 5700, 56467, 8401, 12766, 892, 17234]
}, query2 = {
    LRU: ["Article1", "Article2", "Article1", "Article3", "Article5", 
          "Article4", "Article8", "Article14", "Article2", "Article3"], 
    Client: [394, 594, 4001, 5725, 7057, 7090, 7236, 7242, 7262, 7302],
    round: [3914, 10088, 11107, 0, 3916, 17558, 8401, 4255, 892, 8928]
};

// Convert to a more useful data structure, keyed by client and article
const data = {};
[query1, query2].forEach(function (query, semester) {
    query.Client.forEach(function(clientId, index) {
        var client = data[clientId] = data[clientId] || {};
        var clientArt = client[query.LRU[index]] = client[query.LRU[index]] || [0, 0];
        clientArt[semester] = query.round[index];
    });
});

// Now report on that data
for (const client in data) {
    for (const article in data[client]) {
        const turnovers = data[client][article];
        console.log('Client: ' + client + ', art.: ' + article 
                  + ', semester t/o: ' + turnovers
                  + ' ' + (turnovers[0] === turnovers[1] ? 'equal' : 
                          turnovers[0] < turnovers[1] ? 'increase' : 
                                                        'decrease'));
    }
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: thank you for this good solution. but just I should tell you that I have more than 300 customer and 46 Article. How can I recover it when I change there structure. And another thing the result of my query is dynamically according the choice of user which semester he wants to see it. This one my semesters: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45464774/how-to-compute-the-turnover-each-semester

Comment: My answer contains the code to make the conversion, so you don't really need to change anything. Concerning the semesters: in your question you represented each semester with a separate query variable. In my answer you can place those variables where I have put `[query1, query2]`. Just put there what you have as variables. If you have 3 semesters, put all three there, and you will get inner arrays with 3 values.

Comment: When I see your other question, I really wonder why you made the structure as in `query1`: it just makes things difficult if you put all LRU in one array and all Clients in another. You should have kept related LRU and Client (and round) together in one object, and then make an array of those objects. Anyway, you asked your question based on query1, and query2, so I have answered with that information.

Comment: Thank you, it worked well. But it return just one article (I give you a propoer message) : "Client: 347, art.: ECP, semester t/o: -2510,0 increase". And before this article more than 100 other articles.

Comment: It should give all articles for which that particular client has at least one record in the given semesters. See how it lists more than one article for several users in the sample data (e.g. client 594).

Comment: I'm sorry, but my semester turnover do not represent like in your example. In fact, my semester is the result of my query is represent like above (I edited my question). How can I change it. I posted a request ( of the first semester) above. Thank you very much.

Comment: Honestly, I cannot see the difference between the object literal you added in your question (`{ "LRU": [ "ATSU", "ATSU"` .... etc) and what I have used in my answer (`{ LRU: ["Article1", "Article1",`... etc). What is the difference you are referring to?

Comment: I'm very sorry, yes are same. In your opinion,  why returned just one line just for one article, and before it more than 100 other articles. Thank you.

Comment: I cannot say without seeing an concrete example. Can you provide a fiddle (for example on http://jsfiddle.net/) that demonstrates the issue you have with my code? NB: I hope you understand that the output is ordered by client, and then by article, and that you only get combinations between client and article when there is at least one record in your database that connects them for the selected semesters.

Comment: Yes I understand you well,and your solution worked very well.In fact,I just copy/paste it and I excuted it. it return just this line ( "Client: 347, art.: ECP, semester t/o: 3079,-2510 decrease") and the turnover change dynamically also when I change the semester.I don't have a database I'm working in Palantir cloud I just upload a csv file and I apply the SQL request. So the result of my 2 queries are like above in my question,I see the good result in the query but when I apply your solution in the function it return just one line.I'm sorry I tried to provide you a fiddle but it does not work

Comment: Please give an example of data (formatted as in your question `{ "LRU": [ "ATSU", "ATSU" `....) for which the output is not correct.

Comment: Where I give an example of data ? The data in my question are proper just I took the first 4 lines of each parameter.

Comment: [Here is a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vx95kymu/) with my code and output. Just replace the assignment to `query1` and `query2` with (part of) the data you have the problem with. Make sure the output demonstrates the problem. Save it, and share the link here. I can then have a look at it. I cannot help you if you can't give me the example where it fails.